# Issues setting up react using Create React App

Tags: reactjs, react-native, npm

I am a newbie trying to set up React for the first time. I have an error when I am trying to install it on my computer. I have created a folder in my Documents folder for all the projects I was planning on making, if that makes a difference too. I am not running this in root. Below are the errors I keep getting and I am not sure what they mean. I have googled and found a few forum posts, but none of their solutions work. I am hoping it is something small I have missed.

> Installing template dependencies using npm...
> npm ERR! code ERESOLVE
> npm ERR! ERESOLVE unable to resolve dependency tree
> npm ERR!
> npm ERR!
> While resolving: my-app@0.1.0
> npm ERR! Found: react@18.0.0
> npm ERR!
> node_modules/react
> npm ERR!   react@"^18.0.0" from the root project
> npm ERR!
> npm ERR! Could not resolve dependency:
> npm ERR! peer
> react@"<18.0.0" from @testing-library/react@12.1.5
> npm ERR!
> node_modules/@testing-library/react
> npm ERR!
> @testing-library/react@"^12.0.0" from the root project
> npm ERR!
> npm
> ERR! Fix the upstream dependency conflict, or retry
> npm ERR! this
> command with --force, or --legacy-peer-deps
> npm ERR! to accept an
> incorrect (and potentially broken) dependency resolution.
> npm ERR!
> npm
> ERR! See C:\Users\Luke\AppData\Local\npm-cache\eresolve-report.txt for
> a full report.
>
> npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in: npm ERR!
> C:\Users\Luke\AppData\Local\npm-cache_logs\2022-04-12T04_55_21_058Z-debug-0.log
> `npm install --no-audit --save @testing-library/jest-dom@^5.14.1 @testing-library/react@^12.0.0 @testing-library/user-event@^13.2.1 web-vitals@^2.1.0` failed PS C:\Users\Luke\Documents\React-Projects>

Comment: Run the command `npm install --no-audit --save @testing-library/jest-dom@^5.14.1 @testing-library/react@^12.0.0 @testing-library/user-event@^13.2.1 web-vitals@^2.1.0` in your project directory and use it. Something might have gone wrong with the dependency tree.

Comment: @mchowdam I have just run that, it did add in 58 dependencies. But then when I tried to run the create-react process again the same error came up.

Comment: You don't need to run create-react-app again. The app is already created at first when you run create-react-app but not exactly sure why it's getting failed at adding testing-related libraries. I've also faced the same issue. So after I ran the command from error and directly started my app. It's working fine. You can try that. I'm still exploring a solution to why it failed on create-react-app.

Comment: If you just want a fresh react app, go ahead create a new folder, then run `npx create-react-app@latest my-app`. Once that command succeeds, begin installing your other packages or libraries, previously checking the working versions, some versions might have broken dependencies. Also, check your node.js version, something greater than v12.22.x could help in some instances. (I had some issues installing react v18 while having v17)Let me know if that works for you.

Comment: It still doesn't seems to be working. I've tried running the npx latest and the regular one, and they didn't work but I found that "npm init react-app appname" works even though the dependencies are incorrect.

Comment: You could also remove the node_modules folder and clear the cache.